# I need help figuring out tcp sockets (clsocket)

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, voxel

I am having trouble figuring out sockets i am just asking the server for data at a position (glm::i64vec4) and expecting a response 
but the position gets way off when i get the response and the data for that position reflects that (aka my voxel game make a kinda cool looking but useless mess)


It's probably just me not understanding sockets whatsoever or maybe something weird with this library


one thought i had is it was maybe something to do with mismatching blocking and non blocking on the server and client

but when i switched the server to blocking (and put each client in a seperate thread from each other and the accepting process) it did nothing


if i'm doing something really stupid please tell me i know next to nothing about sockets

here is some code that probably looks horrible

Server Code

```
std::deque <CActiveSocket*> clients;
CPassiveSocket socket;
socket.Initialize();
socket.SetNonblocking();//I'm doing this so i don't need multiple threads for clients
socket.Listen("0.0.0.0",port);
while (1){
    {
        CActiveSocket* c;
        if ((c = socket.Accept()) != NULL){
            clients.emplace_back(c);
        }
    }

    for (CActiveSocket*& c : clients){
        c->Receive(sizeof(glm::i64vec4));
        if (c->GetBytesReceived() == sizeof(glm::i64vec4)){
            chkpkt chk;
            chk.pos = *(glm::i64vec4*)c->GetData();

            LOOP3D(chksize+2){
                chk.data(i,j,k).val = chk.pos.y*chksize+j;
                chk.data(i,j,k).id=0;
            }
            while (c->Send((uint8*)&chk,sizeof(chkpkt)) != sizeof(chkpkt)){}
        }

    }
}
```

Client Code

```
//v is a glm::i64vec4
//fsock is set to Blocking

if(fsock.Send((uint8*)&v,sizeof(glm::i64vec4)))
    if (fsock.Receive(sizeof(chkpkt))){
        tthread::lock_guard<tthread::fast_mutex> lock(wld->filemut);
        wld->ichks[v]=(*(chkpkt*)fsock.GetData()).data;//i tried using the position i get back from the server to set this (instead of v) but that made it to where nothing loaded
        //i checked it and the chunks position never lines up with what i sent
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without your complete application codes it's unrealistic to offer any  suggestions of any particular lines of code correction.

But it seems like you are using [this](https://github.com/DFHack/clsocket) library. It doesn't matter if not, because most of time when doing network programming, socket's weird behavior make some problems somewhat universal. Thus there are a few suggestions for the portion of socket application in your project:

1. It suffices to have BLOCKING sockets.
2. Most of time socket's  `read` have somewhat weird behavior, that is, **it might not receive the requested size of bytes at a time**. Due to this, you need to repeatedly call `read` until the receiving buffer is read thoroughly. For a complete and robust solution you can refer to Stevens's `readn` routine (*[Ref.1]*, page122).

If you are using exactly the library mentioned above, you can see that your `fsock.Receive` eventually calls `recv`. And `recv` is just an variant of `read`*[Ref.2]*, thus the solutions for both of them are just identical. And this pattern might help:

```
while(fsock.Receive(sizeof(chkpkt))>0)
{
  // ...
}
```

Ref.1: [https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~jbreecher/cs280/UNIX%20Network%20Programming(Volume1,3rd).pdf](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/%7Ejbreecher/cs280/UNIX%20Network%20Programming(Volume1,3rd).pdf)
Ref.2: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html#DESCRIPTION